# Rails]Initializing for Fog in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave, fog

I deploy my rails app onto Heroku, and I've set aws access keys on the server as environment variables. However, to test my application in development environment, I need to initialize them somewhere on my local machine. So I decided to the following.

/config/initailizers/init_aws_locally.rb

```
ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'my key'
ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'my secret key'
```

This file is added in `.gitignore`

However, when I upload in development environment, I get this error message:

`Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key`

I think somehow I overlooked a simple step to include my aws keys in my development environment. But I'm not sure why the reason for the error when I already initialized the keys.

For your reference, I'm using carrierwave, S3, and Fog.

*config/initializers/fog.rb*

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'], # required
    :region                 => 'us-east-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'd'                         # required
  config.fog_public     = true                                # optional, defaults to true
end
```

Thank you. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Upload to your development? So you're not developing on your local machine? What is your development OS?

Comment: by upload in development environment, I mean posting an article with an attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid putting any credentials in code. It's such a terrible idea and Heroku has the right idea. So what I do is use RVM and put a file .rvmrc in my project folder. I put .rvmrc in .gitignore as well.

Then you edit .rvmrc to have

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="BLAH"

so on and so forth. Anytime I "cd" into this directory my env is setup for me for that project by RVM. If you're not using RVM there is other alternatives out there.

rails s

and it will have all the environment variables setup that you put in your .rvmrc script. No need for initializer or development only yaml config files that you keep out of source control. From my experience this is the simplest solution.

Comment: Great. That seems a good solution. But I'm still curious why my approach didn't work. Do you have an idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

Your initializers will be run in alphabetical order. See [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html):

> If you have any ordering dependency in your initializers, you can
>   control the load order by naming. For example, 01_critical.rb will be
>   loaded before 02_normal.rb.

The problem you're experiencing is that your fog.rb initializer is running before your init_aws_locally.rb one (because *f* comes before *i*). So ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] has not been defined (yet) when you set fog_credentials.

Comment: this was the solution to my error

fog/core/service.rb:234:in `validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 0):

I went to my shell and typed:

$ echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

and it came back blank. It turns out I recently moved to a new virtual machine and forgot to add this to the .bashrc file.  It's worth checking the shell environment just in case. Once I added those two lines to my .bashrc, everything was happy again.